# mp.isPlaying() is throwing Fatal NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, audio, null, media-player

I have an application that plays sounds on button press.

I'm trying to force the MediaPlayer to mute on incoming call and to continue at normal volume afterwards (in idle mode).

I've wrote the below code to do exactly this, although it's crashing under NullPointerException on the following line.

```
if (mp.isPlaying() && state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
```

Because of

```
mp.isPlaying()
```

Can anyone identify why this is happening? Later on in my code I reference mp to play sounds.

```
    // Release any resources from previous MediaPlayer
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.release();
    }
    // Create a new MediaPlayer to play this sound
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
    mp.setLooping(true);
    mp.start();
```

**This is my on call mute and on idle resume code.**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            if (mp.isPlaying() && state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                mp.setVolume(0,0);
            } else if(mp.isPlaying() && state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                mp.setVolume(1,1);
            } else if(mp.isPlaying() && state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                mp.setVolume(0,0);
            }
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        }
    };

    TelephonyManager mgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if(mgr != null) {
        mgr.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
```

I cannot understand why mp is Null if it's called later on in the application. If it's not playing will that return null? If so how would I get around this.

**This is my whole activity as requested.**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                if (mp.isPlaying() && state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                    mp.setVolume(0,0);
                } else if(mp.isPlaying() && state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    mp.setVolume(1,1);
                } else if(mp.isPlaying() && state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                    mp.setVolume(0,0);
                }
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            }
        };

        TelephonyManager mgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if(mgr != null) {
            mgr.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }

        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_1);
        Button button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_2);
        Button button3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_3);
        Button button4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_4);
        Button button5=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_5);
        Button button6=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_6);
        Button button7=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_7);
        Button button8=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_8);

        final ImageView button_stop=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.button_stop);
        ImageView button_rate=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.button_rate);
        ImageView button_exit=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.button_exit);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
        button4.setOnClickListener(this);
        button5.setOnClickListener(this);
        button6.setOnClickListener(this);
        button7.setOnClickListener(this);
        button8.setOnClickListener(this);
        button_stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(null!=mp){
                    mp.release();
                    button_stop.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_volume_muted);
                     }
            }});

        button_exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.cancel(0);
                finish();
            }});

        button_rate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String str ="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=example";
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(str)));

            }

       ;{ 

       }});




        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("example")
                .setContentText("example.");
        // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        final Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        mBuilder.setOngoing(true);
        // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
        // started Activity.
        // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
        // your application to the Home screen.

        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        int mId = 0;
        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        int resId;
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_1:
            resId = R.raw.birdsong;
            break;
        case R.id.button_2:
            resId = R.raw.electrifying_thunderstorms;
            break;
        case R.id.button_3:
            resId = R.raw.fan;
            break;
        case R.id.button_4:
            resId = R.raw.jungle_river;
            break;
        case R.id.button_5:
            resId = R.raw.pig_frogs;
            break;
        case R.id.button_6:
            resId = R.raw.predawn;
            break;
        case R.id.button_7:
            resId = R.raw.shower;
            break;
        case R.id.button_8:
            resId = R.raw.twilight;
            break;
        default:
            resId = R.raw.birdsong;
            break;
        }
        // Release any resources from previous MediaPlayer
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.release();
        }
        // Create a new MediaPlayer to play this sound
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();

        ImageView button_stop=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.button_stop);
        button_stop.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_volume_on);

    }{


                        }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if(null!=mp){
            mp.release();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    }
```

**LOGCAT**

```
02-27 12:55:12.306: W/dalvikvm(887): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
02-27 12:55:12.326: E/AndroidRuntime(887): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 12:55:12.326: E/AndroidRuntime(887): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-27 12:55:12.326: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at me.soundasleep.app.MainActivity$1.onCallStateChanged(MainActivity.java:36)
02-27 12:55:12.326: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.telephony.PhoneStateListener$2.handleMessage(PhoneStateListener.java:369)
02-27 12:55:12.326: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-27 12:55:12.326: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-27 12:55:12.326: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-27 12:55:12.326: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 12:55:12.326: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-27 12:55:12.326: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-27 12:55:12.326: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-27 12:55:12.326: E/AndroidRuntime(887):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-27 12:55:12.358: W/ActivityManager(292):   Force finishing activity me.soundasleep.app/.MainActivity
02-27 12:55:12.366: W/WindowManager(292): Failure taking screenshot for (328x583) to layer 21010
02-27 12:55:12.656: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
02-27 12:55:12.886: W/ActivityManager(292): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{4132e3e0 u0 me.soundasleep.app/.MainActivity}
02-27 12:55:13.149: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
02-27 12:55:16.186: I/Process(887): Sending signal. PID: 887 SIG: 9
02-27 12:55:16.206: I/ActivityManager(292): Process EXAMPLE (pid 887) has died.
```

Comment: Can you post your whole activity?

Comment: Updated the question to include the whole activity

Comment: Can you also paste stacktrace?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what stacktrace is, but I've updated the question to include my LOGCAT error

Comment: Well, what if you get an `onCallStateChanged` before you've created your `MediaPlayer` instance?

Comment: You are creating `mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);` in onClick() and you are using mp in onCreate(). Create the object so that mp is created before using in onCreate().

Comment: Walk through the code in your head.  Your app starts, then without doing anything else, the phone rings.  At this point, where is `mp` initialised?  Following this, `// Create a new MediaPlayer to play this sound
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);`, mp cannot be null since you create a new instance.  Without spending a long time working through your code, it seems the correct thing is to check for null in the phone state listener before trying to manipulate the player.

Comment: A simple fix is to check if mp is null, then bypass all your onCallStateChanged() and just call super.onCallStateChanged()

Comment: Taken your advice on board MDMalik :)

Comment: @MDMalik OP should choose whatever the answer he pleases. He's not forced to accept an answer just because it was posted first. You're the one who decided to invest time on your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is simple.

You did declare `mp` in the class, but on create you haven't initialized it. Hence when it come `onCreate` method, `mp` is null.. Hence the error.

My suggestion would be do this in `onCreate` method

```
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.birdsong);
```

Don't play it. just initalize it. It won't crash

Code for better understanding

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   //this line is EXTRA    ///
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.birdsong);

    PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            if (mp.isPlaying() && state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                mp.setVolume(0,0);
            } else if(mp.isPlaying() && state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                mp.setVolume(1,1);
            } else if(mp.isPlaying() && state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                mp.setVolume(0,0);
            }
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 4):

The `PhoneStateListener()` is being executed before creating the `MediaPlayer`, that's why you are getting null pointer exception. Put the following method before declare its listener `phoneStateListener`:

```
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
    mp.setLooping(true);
    mp.start();

    PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            if (mp.isPlaying() && state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                mp.setVolume(0,0);
            } else if(mp.isPlaying() && state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                mp.setVolume(1,1);
            } else if(mp.isPlaying() && state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                mp.setVolume(0,0);
            }
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        }
    };
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Works perfectly now than you very much. Such a simple fix for a newbie error :)

Answer (score 1):

You are creating

`mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);` in `onClick()` and you are using `mp` in `onCreate()`.

Create the object so that `mp` is created before using in `onCreate()`

Comment: Thank you very much! works perfectly. I forgot that the code is read in order and that mp had not been created yet.